# Trace log in .Net. Why?

Tags: .net, logging, trace

When we can create simple text log file(.log) using textwriters So why there is Trace and debug classess. I mean what is the actual need of Trace and loging.

When to use them with a simple and good example!

I tried them in my code the default output is in output window. I tried:

`Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("TextWriterOutput.log", "myListener"));
  Trace.TraceInformation("Test message.");
  Trace.WriteLine("suren","General - Error Tracing Enabled");`

but this is not writing in the file specified!!

Thanks
Suren

Comment: Write to the output window, when you don't want to clutter log files with trace output. And allows alot more detail, like entering / exiting methods, variable values etc.

Comment: have some chunk of codes for a explanation. Or a link to good example.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debug is a way to log if your project compilation mode is in "Debug". Proper compiler in "Release" mode, C# or VB, or any other, won't compile/execute any logging with Debug class.

Trace would do even in Debug or Release compilation mode.

Also, both are a simpler way to have an universal logger, which can output to any kind of stream, because you've trace listeners that can handle in a customized way how to write log's text wherever you want:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t.aspx

Debug/Trace have a default listener implementation that ouputs texts to Visual Studio's output window. But as I said, you can output anywhere with your custom listeners.

You'd like to use them because no one wants to reinvent wheels and if the simpler out-of-the-box .NET solution for basic logging fits your needs, and anyone knows about it, why you wouldn't use it? :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.flush.aspx Simply follow the sample code Microsoft provides. No flush no output.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the listener to check if it's invoked?